# DAG import Error for init actions - DataprocCreateClusterOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

There is an existing code that creates Google Dataproc cluster using `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`. I just want to add initialisation actions while creating the cluster. I tried to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480669/how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-a-google-dataproc-cluster-using-airflow-dataprocope) solution. Here is the code snippet,

```
DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    # ...
    init_actions_uris = ['gs://<BUCKET>/path/to/init/action.sh'],
    # ...
)
```

But I am getting the bellow error while importing DAG into Airflow,

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to DataprocCreateClusterOperator (task_id: task123). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'init_actions_uris': ['gs://<BUCKET>/path/to/init/action.sh]}
```

Am I missing something? How do I add init actions within `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`?

Comment: Try using [ClusterGenerator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#generating-cluster-config)

Comment: @blackbishop I saw this. But there is a whole lot of code already written using DataprocClusterCreateOperator. Should I have to re write of everything using ClusterGenerator?